# Как клонировать только одну папку из git-репозитория

Tags: git, yii, github

Добрый вечер,

Работаю с yii. Хотел бы использовать одно из расширений как submodule (ман: [Starting your Yii Project Reference Guide (with Git VCS in Linux)](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/307/starting-your-yii-project-reference-guide-with-git-vcs-in-linux/)). [Собственно расширение](https://github.com/clevertech/YiiBooster). Вопрос: как клонировать в проект только папку src расширения?

Comment: Вопрос-дубликат: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/411585/

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю текущее состояние Git, скачивать придётся все каталоги из YiiBooster. Можно настроить [sparce checkout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/413051/32432) чтобы распаковывались не все файлы, но это только удалит лишние файлы, оставив единственную директорию `src`. Такую настройку нужно будеет проводить во всех репозиториях ([см. также](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17693008/266720)), само по `git submodule init` оно не возникнет.

Мои варианты дейсвий:

1. Смириться с лишними файлами и `src/`;
2. Смириться с `src/`, но подавить лишние файлы при помощи sparce checkout во всех репозиториях разработчиков (т.е. написать специальный скрипт, который будет настраивать git и сабмодули);
3. Держать свой вариант ("форк") репозитория YiiBooster, в котором `src/` перенесено в корень, а всё остальное удалено, и обновлять его при помощи [`git subtree`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging). Submodule будет указывать на ваш форк;
4. Не использовать submodule вообще, просто разместить `src/` из YiiBooster'а к себе в репозиторий. Обновления из upstream можно делать при помощи subtree merge.