# Клонирование только определенной директории

Tags: git, git-clone

Подскажите, как-то можно в git клонировать не весь проект ветки master, а только 1 директорию из этой ветки? И в дальнейшем работать с ней?

Comment: Никак. Это невозможно по определению.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/2908793

там же первый ответ поясняет, почему это в корне неверно.

Comment: @Etki: ссылка указывает на другой ответ, который объясняет как делать *sparse checkout*, то есть позволяет только заданный набор путей в рабочей директории иметь (в том числе и одну директорию).

Comment: @jfs я на него ссылку и кидал.

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я знаю, скачивать придётся всё равно весь master. Но можно чтобы "распаковывались" не все файлы.

```
git init имяреп
cd имяреп
git remote add origin ссылка
git fetch
```

На этом этапе master (и все другие ветви) будут скачаны, но не распакованы.

Теперь включим спецрежим:

```
git config core.sparseCheckout true
```

Укажем какие файлы мы хотим

```
echo вот/этот/каталог >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
```

И распакуем файлы:

```
git checkout origin/master -B master
```

В итоге `вот/этот/каталог/файл.txt` попадёт в рабочий каталог, а `не/тот/каталог/файл.txt` нет.

Если в репозитории много ветвей и нужно экономить траффик, можно скачивать не все (например, после `git remote add` изменить файл `.git/config`, чтобы было не `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, а только `fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`), а также скачивать не всю историю (`git fetch --depth=50`).

Comment: А есть ли способ на 1м этапе, что дан @vi в ответе, обойти и не скачивать весь репозиторий. А то есть репо по 1Гб, а мне необходимо работать с изменением в 5 Мб(Тем более объём HDD сильно ограничен)

Comment: Даже больше интересует частичное клонирование (конкретной директории)