# Можно ли клонировать репозиторий частично?

Tags: git, git-clone

Как можно клонировать содержимое репозитория без родительской папки.

```
git clone git@***.***.***.***:/opt/git/site1
```

На тестовом сервере добавил сайт, папка сайта `/home/bitrix/ext_www/dev.site1.ru`

При выполнении данной команды `git` у меня в папке `dev.site1.ru/site1/*`

Можно ли как-нибудь клонировать содержимое папки site1

Comment: Вероятно, решение здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/411585/181472

Answer (score 2):

`git clone %url% %dir%`, где `%dir%` - имя той папки, в которой должен оказаться репозиторий (должна не существовать или быть пустой на момент клонирования).

например:

```
git clone git@github.com/etki/repo.git dev.site1.ru
```

В этом случае содержимое репозитория окажется в `{текущая папка}/dev.site1.ru`

Comment: При клонировании у меня получается такое  так /home/bitrix/ext_www/dev.site1.ru/site1/тут файлы сайта

git clone git@...:/opt/git/site1 dev.site1.ru

Comment: @murad30, не понял комментария, добавил пример.

Comment: Насколько я понял, автору другое нужно было. Он хочет не указать папку в которую клонирует, а клонировать репозиторий частично. [Т.е. не все папки скачать, а некоторые](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/411585/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8#comment411617_411585).

Answer (score -1):

```
git clone git@...:/path/to/project.git .
```